# How to change 37 bits in a byte array to all complement of existing value

Tags: java, byte, arrays, bit

I have a byte array `myByteArray[82]`

I want to change exactly 37 bits in this array to the complement value. ie. if bit0 has a '1' I want to change it to '0'. I need to change first 37 such bits to introduce error in this byte array.

Please suggest how to do this

Comment: Which 37 bits? Leftmost? Rightmost? Leftmost (or rightmost) 37 1-bits wherever they occur?  Please tell us what you mean with an example (it doesn't have to be 82 bytes long) and, more important, _show what you have already tried_.

Comment: thanks for the reply... actually I just want to change ANY 37 bits (invert them) .. to introduce random array in the byte array of length 82

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do. My best understanding is that you have an array of 82 bytes and you want to invert the lowest 37 bits of the array. Since a byte is 8 bits, so you can do this:

```
byte[] myByteArray = new byte[82];
// invert lowest 32 bits, 8 at a time
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    myByteArray[i] = (byte)(~myByteArray[i]);
}
// invert next five bits
myByteArray[4] = (byte) (
    (myByteArray[4] & 0xE0) // top 3 bits unchanged
    |
    ((~myByteArray[4)) & 0x1F) // bottom 5 bits inverted
    );
```

Comment: thank you so much!!  I shall study this code and learn how to do this!! really helpful!

Answer (score 2):

try

```
    byte[] a82 = ...
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
    while (set.size() < 37) {
        set.add((int) (Math.random() * 82));
    }
    for (int i : set) {
        int ibyte = i / 8;
        int ibit = i % 8;
        int m = 1 << ibit;
        a[ibyte] ^= m;
    }
```

Comment: This will change up to 37 bits at random in the 82 bytes.  It will certainly introduce error.  I like it!

Comment: Nice approach. +1 However, OP has 82*8 = 656 bits available; your code randomly selects 37 of the first 82 only. Also, rather than using `(int)(Math.random() * 656)`, it would be clearer to create a `java.util.Random` object and use `rand.nextInt(656)`. Finally, instead of `i / 8`, use `i >> 3` and instead of `i % 8`, use `i & 7`. (The compiler might automatically make these last two optimizations, but it can't hurt to do it yourself.)

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
int nBits = 37;

int i = 0;

for (; i<nBits / 8; ++i)
    myByteArray[i] = (byte)((byte) myByteArray[i] ^ 0xFF);

myByteArray[i] = (byte)(myByteArray[i] ^ ((0xFF >>> 5) ^ 0xFF));
```

Whether or not you do the final XOR with the 0xFF on the last line depends on whether you consider the most significant bit to be the first bit (then use it) or the last bit (then omit it);

Comment: I edited the code so that it works correctly.  Waaaa, I forgot that Java was so much less friendly for bit-twiddling than C.

Answer (score 0):

To invert a specific 37 bits, randomly chosen:

```
// array of 82 bytes with 37 selected bits set to 1, all the rest zero
// you could generate this programmatically as well if you need a different
// set of bits each time, but your question implies you don't
byte[] mask = { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x80, .... 0x00 };

for (int i=0; i<myByteArray.length; i++)
{
    myByteArray[i] ^= mask[i];
}
```

Use the bit-exclusive-or operator `^`.  The truth table for xor is

```
    M a s k
    | 0 | 1
D  -+---+---
a  0| 0 | 1
t  -+---+---
a  1| 1 | 0
```

Wherever there's a 1 in the mask the corresponding bit in the data will be flipped.